# Where does bibtex look for .bib files?

Tags: bibtex, windows, texworks

I'm trying to get bibtex to work using TeXworks, and I'm getting an error message saying that it can't find the .bib file.  I've got the .bib file in the same folder where the .tex file is.  Why can't it open it?  Does it not look in the local folder?  If not, where is it looking?

Comment: `echo $BIBINPUTS`

Comment: Check if  you have only the parameter `$basename` for  bibtex configuration in  texworks preferences.

Comment: I'm using the pdfLatex+MakeIndex+BibTex processing tool combination.  The arguments are: --pdf, --synctex=1, --clean, --tex-option=--enable-write18, $fullname

Comment: @gandolf your suggestion implies that there is some kind of command line interface where I could type this.  I'm using Texworks, how do I enter 'echo $BIBINPUTS'?

Comment: On Linux or MacOS type `echo $BIBINPUTS` on your console.

Comment: @gandolf ok thanks, but I'm using TexWorks on windows, and on windows command line 'echo $BIBINPUTS' just returns '$BIBINPUTS'